# Can I figure out when transaction was submitted?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

can I find out when a transaction was submitted to blockchain?
Imagine transaction was sumitted at 10:00 AM. It was added to a block at 10:20. Can I find time of the transaction submission (10:00 AM) later?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is just a general question, but when you submit a transaction you should receive a tx hash. You can use a site like etherscan.io to see the status of that transaction.

For example, https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc741130b8d24ba9708af7bdf48e8dc1404b36d4a8b92bffaaf03c7f7482fcd58

Comment: Thanks, I've used it :) I don't quite well follow what happens after. I failed to find the explanation. My guess is that "submission" time is not available in blockchain after a transaction was to a block. Submission time could be hacked, but "add-to-block" time can't be hacked since it's value based on consensus.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think this information is stored. Although a pending transaction will show up on etherscan.io (including it seems now when it was first tracked), the submission time is not stored past the point at which the transaction is added to a block. You can only capture this information in pseudo-real time.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to find exact spec definition. I failed to find it... :(

Comment: There will be no spec for 'this data is not saved in the chain' if it's not part of the dataset. I was looking for something similar. Submission time is just down to the node, is able to track age as part of it's eviction (which I think I found referenced in github comments). Submission and re-broadcast seem to be not well tracked.